# Evaluate function on a grid

Tags: functions

Beginning Mathematica user here, coming from R, Python, etc. I have a (slightly more complex) function as such:

```
f[x_,y_] := x^2 + y^2
```

And I also have lists of values as such:

```
xval = {3,6,7}
yval = {9,11,4}
```

I know I can apply the function for "matching pairs" of x and y by doing:

```
f[x,y]
```

But what about for all possible combinations of x and y? (The equivalent in R would require expand.grid)

Comment: `Table[f[x,y],{x,xval},{y,yval}]` and then maybe flattening it by `Flatten`?

Comment: For f[x, y] == g[x] +  h[y] as in the specific example, Outer[Plus, g[xvals], h[yvals]] might be fast. Should be for xvals^2 and yvals^2.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. All good. I will take the answer below

Comment: Maybe so, but the answers I've gotten here are different than in those posts you mention. I wouldn't flag it as a duplicate because the solution is different.

Comment: @dleal the solution here is nicer for my taste, the two threads really should be merged or something.

Comment: @aardvark2012 i agree with the post above. The answer here is better and different than in the posts you mention as duplicates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to apply `f` to all the possible values -- one is to observe that f is applied to the outer product of xval and yval:

```
xval = {3, 6, 7};
yval = {9, 11, 4};
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
Outer[f, xval, yval]
```

A closely related alternative is to use DistanceFunction (with f playing the role of your distance)

```
DistanceMatrix[xval, yval, DistanceFunction -> f]
```

Comment: I like this answer better, than the one in the linked dupe. +1